# Why does value_counts(dropna=False) evaluate NaN as a second True value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm confused as to why Series.value_counts() is treating NaN as a separate True value.

I understand that NaN, when evaluated as a bool, evaluates to True.  But when I create a series with bools and NaN, the series is of type object, not of type bool. So why does it evaluate it as a bool when counting the unique values?

Here's a simple example of what I mean:

```
s = pd.Series([True, False, np.nan])
s.value_counts(dropna=False)
```

outputs

```
True     1
False    1
True     1
dtype: int64
```

Versions:

> ```
> numpy 1.18.1
> pandas 1.0.1
> python 3.7.6
> ```

Comment: It is output True     1
False    1
NaN      1
dtype: int64

Comment: It looks like an undocumented regression bug that was fixed in pandas 1.0.4 at least, just upgrade to the latest version. I could not find any information about this bug in the [changelog](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.0.5.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cs95 is right and upgrading to pandas 1.0.5 fixed my issue.